# Check if same file exists in another directory using Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, if-statement

I'm new to bash and would like your help; couldn't find an answer for this case. 
I'm trying to check if the files in one directory exist in another directory

Let's say I have the path /home/public/folder/ (here I have several files)
and I want to check if the files exist in /home/private/folder2

I tried that

```
for file in $firstPath/*
do
   if [ -f $file ]; then
   (ask if to over write etc.. rest of the code)
```

And also

```
for file in $firstPath/*
do
   if [ -f $file/$secondPath ]; then
   (ask if to over write etc.. rest of the code)
```

Both don't work; it seems that in the first case, it compares the files in the first path (so it always ask me if I want to overwrite although it doesn't exist in the second path) 
And in the second case, it doesn't go inside the if statement. 
How could I fix that?

Comment: you got the `$file` and `$secondPath` backwards.  Try `if [ -f "${secondPath}/$(basename ${file}) ]`

Comment: Use `basename` to extract the name portion of the path from `$file`.  So something like `if [ -f $secondPath/$(basename "$file") ]; then`.

Comment: [How to clean duplicates existing in one folder from another recursively?](https://askubuntu.com/q/236809) More generally, [bash dedupe files in another directory](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+dedupe+files+in+another+directory).

Comment: How we can check *.txt files available in /home/tmp directory ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have a construct like `for file in $firstPath/*`, the value of `$file` is going to include the value of `$firstPath`, which does not exist within `$secondPath`. You need to strip the path in order to get the bare filename.

In traditional POSIX shell, the canonical way to do this was with an external tool called [`basename`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/basename.html). You can, however, achieve what is generally thought to be equivalent functionality using [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), thus:

```
for file in "$firstPath"/*; do
   if [[ -f "$secondPath/${file##*/}" ]]; then
       # file exists, do something
   fi
done
```

The `${file##*/}` bit is the important part here. Per the documentation linked above, this means "the `$file` variable, with everything up to the last `/` stripped out." The result should be the same as what `basename` produces.

As a general rule, you should [quote your variables in bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F). In addition, consider using `[[` instead of `[` unless you're actually writing POSIX shell scripts which need to be portable. You'll have a more extensive set of tests available to you, and more predictable handling of variables. There are [other differences too](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031).

Comment: I know what you mean, but your last sentence seems to co-mingle using `[[` and ... don't forget to quote your variables (within it). I know you didn't mean them together, but it may not be clear to a new reader that `"[w]ord splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the words between the [[ and ]]; ..."`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Good point, thanks. I've reworded, and added external references.

Comment: @ghoti How we can check *.txt files available in /home/tmp directory ??

Comment: @BhageshArora .. I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Does it relate to this question or my answer? What do you want to check?

Comment: @ghoti For example I have file name sample_1_2_3.txt. In arguments I am getting only some of prefix not full name of file name example - sample, 1 & 2. Now How we can check sample_1_2_*.txt present in /home/tmp/ directory or not ?